# Probability Distribution at each Simulation Period using Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, simulations, distribution, geometric-brownian

I am using the equation $S_t = S_0e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma\epsilon\sqrt{t}} $ to simulate a  financial metric at each $t$, where $t=1$ and $T=5$.  Stated in plain English, I am trying to simulate the financial metric at the end of every year, for $5$ years.  Additionally, for this exercise it is important that I know the path of the metric as well. When looking at the distributions of this financial metric at each $t$, after a high number of trials, they start from something that resembles a lognormal distribution at $t=1$ and then decay to 0 with each successive $t$.  Can anyone explain the mathematics behind this or why GBM behaves this way?[image: Distributions at each t]

Note: Volatility is around 20% and I am using annual volatility.

Comment: What is the value of $\mu$? If $\mu-0.5\sigma^2 <0$ the process tends almost surely to zero even though the mean is $S_0e^{\mu t}$.

Comment: $\mu = .008$ and $\sigma^2 = .05$ so $\mu - .5\sigma^2\lt 0$ but all of the inputs are based on "real world" data.  Is there any remedy to this scenario? I've found that instead of taking a random variable and using that in the equation, taking the difference, $\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1}$, helps the situation a bit but I'm not sure if that is correct in a theoretical/mathematical framework.

Comment: This behaviour is due to mean being very low relative to variance. Are you sure your estimates are correct?

Comment: Yes the data is correct, I suppose I can't change that.  In this context thought would taking the difference between the random variables ($\epsilon$) be inappropriate?

Comment: Hi: Is it possible that there is a mistake in the units used in the estimation of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. As fesman pointed out, it's very strange to have a process where the variance is more than six times the mean. Maybe the mean is a monthly estimate and the variance is a yearly estimate ? Just a guess.

Comment: @markleeds for $\mu$ I am using the 5 year risk free rate and for volatility I calculated it using daily volatility for five years and then annualized it by multiplying by $\sqrt{252}$.

Comment: Daily volatility of what?

Comment: Hi: It sounds like both the mean and the volatility are supposed to be yearly numbers, I think. I totally don't understand the use of the five year risk free rate for $\mu$. If it's an asset, then you need to use the asset's returns ( either daily, weekly, monthly whatever ) and annualize them. For volatility, $\sigma$, if it's the daily volatility of the asset over the 5 years and you averaged it and then annualized it like you described, then that sounds almost okay but then you need to either A) square it or B) multiply by 252 ( not the square root ) to get back to variance